# What is this C# generic constraint does: public class ValueObject<T> where T : ValueObject<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I don't understand this generic constraint where the constraint is the same type as the class.

```
public class ValueObject<T> where T : ValueObject<T>
```

What does this constraints? When it is used?

Comment: It simply means it is a value object of another value object.

Comment: There is also a nice article from Eric Lippert [Curiouser and curiouser](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic T must inherit of gived type.
where T : BaseClass.